# xpath: How to select Parent Element with conditions on Multiple Child Elements?

Tags: r, xpath, xml2

I am using 'xml2' library in R to read an xml file for data analysis.

In the sample xml below, how do I return the parent 'row' elements whose child elements meet multiple conditions?

I want to select 'row' elements that has a 'year' element equal to "2018" and 'vehicle_type' element equal to "scooter"?

```
<rows>
    <row>
      <vehicle_type>scooter</vehicle_type>
      <year>2018</year>
      <trip_duration>358</trip_duration>
    </row>
    <row>
      <vehicle_type>scooter</vehicle_type>
      <year>2019</year>
      <trip_duration>358</trip_duration>
    </row>
    <row>
      <vehicle_type>bicycle</vehicle_type>
      <year>2018</year>
      <trip_duration>358</trip_duration>
    </row>
</rows>
```

I used the '|' symbol as AND operator. However, it returns an error.

This is the code I tried so far:

```
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
tripXML <- read_xml('trips-1.xml')

rows <- xml_find_all(tripXML, "//row[./year/text()='2018' | ./vehicle_type/text()='scooter']")
```

This is the error message in RStudio.

```
Error in xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = Inf) : xmlXPathEval: 3 object left on the stack
```

I would like to select this row value:

```
<row>
      <vehicle_type>scooter</vehicle_type>
      <year>2018</year>
      <trip_duration>358</trip_duration>
</row>
```

Hope anybody could help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` operator is not the `and` operator in XPath, but rather the *merge nodesets* operator ([Look here at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp) for some inspirations). So to sanitize your expression, simply use the `and` operator:

```
//row[year/text()='2018' and vehicle_type/text()='scooter']
```

Then you'll get your desired output.
(I also removed the leading `./` because they weren't necessary)